# include srv files in python catkin project

Tags: ros, python2.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently having some issues with importing my service files into my project.
i can't import into my service_def.py file.. Why is that not possible?

I made it as a rosnode, my src folder of the catkin_workspace looks like this

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
└── service
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── service
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── service_def.py
    │       └── service_def.pyc
    ├── package.xml
    ├── setup.py
    ├── src
    │   └── service_node.py
    └── srv
        ├── get.srv
        ├── set.srv
        └── __init__.py
```

service_def.py is defined as such

```
from ..srv import *
```

And my service_node.py which i `rosrun` imports service_def.py

```
import service.service_def
```

So why cant I import my service messages in service_def.py?

error message:

```
k@k:~/python_service/src$ rosrun service service_node.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/python_service/src/service/src/service_node.py", line 5, in <module>
    import service.service_def
  File "/home/k/python_service/src/service/include/service/service_def.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..srv import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248646/include-srv-files-in-python-catkin-project/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error says, you are trying to do a relative import (i.e. using `..`). Instead, since you are already setting `service` as a package in your `setup.py` file you can used that package name directly by changing:

`from ..srv import *`   in `service_def.py` to  `from service.service_def import *`.

Here's an MWE for the:

**Structure:**

```
service/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
├── src
│   └── service_node
└── srv
    ├── get.srv
    ├── __init__.py
    └── set.srv
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(service)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
   rospy
   std_msgs
   message_generation
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
   get.srv
   set.srv
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
)
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>service</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The service package</description>

  <maintainer email="jsanch@todo.todo">jsanch</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
</package>
```

**service_node**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
import service.srv


def main():
    print("Creating set")
    x = service.srv.set
    print("Creating get")
    y = service.srv.get

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('service_node', anonymous=True)
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-11-23**:
but that doesn't solve the problem.. It doesn't import the srv files?

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-11-23**:
@215 Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-11-23**:
where are you defining /running the services?

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-11-23**:
@215 The services are defined in the `srv` folder, and are being used in the `service_node`; `x` is defined as a `set` service and `y` as a `get` service.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-11-23**:
but..? i want to define the how it should set and get things.
don't you need a rospy.spin()?

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-11-23**:
@215 The code I provided was meant to be a minimal working example. For a tutorial on how to use a server you could check this [site](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29). Also is more convenient to define your services in a separate package.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2016-11-23**:
well..  A simple line like this  `get_service = rospy.Service('_get_service', get, getConfiguration)` gives me a error message that it cant find `get`..

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-11-23**:
Try replacing `get` with `service.srv.get`.